# How to reach the logs of Log Analytics agent extension for VMSS?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-defender

I've followed the manual remediation for the following recommendation from Microsoft Defender For Cloud regarding Virtual Machine Scale Set:

> **Log Analytics agent should be installed on virtual machine scale sets**

> Defender for Cloud collects data from your Azure virtual machines
> (VMs) to monitor for security vulnerabilities and threats. Data is
> collected using the Log Analytics agent, formerly known as the
> Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA), which reads various security-related
> configurations and event logs from the machine and copies the data to
> your workspace for analysis. You'll also need to follow that procedure
> if your VMs are used by an Azure managed service such as Azure
> Kubernetes Service or Azure Service Fabric. You cannot configure
> auto-provisioning of the agent for Azure virtual machine scale sets.
> To deploy the agent on virtual machine scale sets (including those
> used by Azure managed services such as Azure Kubernetes Service and
> Azure Service Fabric), follow the procedure in the remediation steps.

which was to [install the Log Analytics agent extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-agent?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Security#add-the-agent-extension-via-azure-cli) (in my case for Linux). The extension was installed properly and I can see it in the portal in the VMSS resource.

My understanding is that this should result in the agent collecting some logs. Is there a place where I can find them? The page linked above refers to Performance Counters of Service Fabric, which I don't believe applies to my case.

Are the logs visible in the Log Analytics workspace? If so, what should be the query?
Do I have to install Insights as well to see any actual logs/metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the logs visible in Log Analytics workspace? If so, what should be
> the query? Do I have to install Insights as well to see any actual
> logs/metrics?

The logs are visible in Log Analytics workspace.

**Sample Heartbeat Query**

```
Heartbeat  
| where OSType == 'Linux'  
| where Category != 'Azure Monitor Agent'  
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SourceComputerId  
| sort by Computer  
| render table
```

We downloaded the agent and installed it on Linux VMSS.
[image]

Logs in Log Analytics Workspace

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed they are there. However one weird thing I noticed is that they started showing up about 12 hours after deploying the agent. Did you experience something similar?