# Migrating to Azure Monitor Agent when using Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm running an Azure App Service (ASP.NET 7) and it has a pretty vanilla App Insights configuration (enabled via the dashboard). I was poking around the Log Analyitics Resource blade of the dashboard and saw this message:

> The Log Analytics agents (MMA.OMS) used to collect logs from virtual
> machines and servers will no longer be supported from August 31, 2024.
> Plan to migrate to Azure Monitor Agent before this date. Learn more
> about migrating to Azure Monitor Agent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-migration

These steps seem to be for scenarios where you're installing the agent manually on a VM/Server. I wanted to confirm that no action is necessary for users of App Service?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899133/how-to-reach-the-logs-of-log-analytics-agent-extension-for-vmss/75919541#75919541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> These steps seem to be for scenarios where you're installing the agent manually on a VM/Server. I wanted to confirm that no action is necessary for users of App Service?
```

***Yes, You do not need to take any action in your Azure App service***, even if its diagnostic settings are connected to the Log analytics workspace.

The warning is related to the Classic legacy agent management system created for Azure VM's to log the VM's system logs, internal process logs, and get insights into the VM systems and processes. Now, You do not need to use this Classic Legacy agent management system and send the VM logs to the Azure Log analytics workspace for getting insights. As the new Agent management is available in Log analytics workspace.

**The warning:-**

[image]

**New Agent management:-**

[image]

***These Monitoring agent management Classic and New is specific to Windows Server and Linux Server that are the VM's Azure or Hybrid to get VM specific logs and not app services.***

You can directly enable the Agent management for your VM's by either creating data collection rules like below:-

[image]

Or directly connect VM and install monitoring agent inside it by using Azure Monitor:-

[image]

Now, ***Coming to app services, If you already have application insights configured for your app, you do not need to take any other step to get insights of your app.***

But Log analytics will come into picture when you send your Azure App service Logs via Azure app service Diagnostic settings to Log analytics workspace like below:-

***Select your Web app in Azure Portal > In the left pane > Select Diagnostic Settings> Add Diagnostic settings > Select the logs you want to send to the desired Log analytics workspace and click on save.***

[image]

[image]

You can then directly query the Azure App services logs by clicking on Logs section of your web app like below:-

[image]

**References:-**

[Monitor App Service with Azure Monitor - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-app-service)

[Azure Monitor Agent overview - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agents-overview)